# What slider does the BBC use?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, gallery

I would like to know if you could tell me if there is a jQuery Plugin exactly like:
http://www.bbc.co.uk/ 's "Discovery Zone".

Would be helpful if you have some ideas.

To be on the same page:
I am talking about this area: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wil5J.jpg

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Just for information, the BBC don't use jQuery. They made their own javascript library called Glow (which is now open source) for a host of reasons to do with dependability etc as it's a publicly funded organisation. http://www.bbc.co.uk/glow/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan they do use jQuery - they load 1.6.2 on the homepage .... (granted not for the slider ...)

Comment: So they do. I assume that appeared when their new layout went live a couple of weeks ago. The previous version definately never had it. I guess they realised it was a little silly not to use jQuery and how much work would be involved in making Glow consistent with all current and future browsers.

Comment: I think that the requirement to support a browser that jQuery didn't support was dropped (due to its falling market share) so jQuery became viable under the rules they have to operate under. I wasn't paying too much attention at the time since my project needed to support all sorts of embedded browsers which just about every library fails horribly on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the source, it's http://www.bbc.co.uk/glow/docs/1.7/furtherinfo/widgets/carousel/ which is a part of the Glow library.

It does look like they used http://static.bbc.co.uk/frameworks/jcarousel/0.1.6/modules/jcarousel-1.js (homepage: http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/ ) before, or maybe use it for other stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I saw a news a while ago about BBC having it's own JS library [Glow](http://www.bbc.co.uk/glow/) - is  available under the Apache Licence.

Comment: Thanks Elzo, I found that one as well, but there is not a ready to go solution such as their discovery zone. If i had to write it in my own with glow Id rather prefer jquery than. But I dont want to write it on my own in the best case : )